# Script delete files in a folder and also tries to delete other files outside the folder

Tags: batch-file

I use a batch script to delete some files in a local folder, where the script is located. Nevertheless the script is tring to delete files located in some other location (the Program files (x86) folder), which is scary (hopefully these files are read-protected): I get the following error messages:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\PathToFile\TimeSeries.DFSGenericBridge.dll Access is denied
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\PathToFile\ClimateChange.DfsReader.dll Access is denied
>   ...

I thought that the for loop was only looping inside the folder where the script is located.

```
@echo off
Set exten=*.dfs*
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('Where /F %exten%') do (
       del %%F
    )
)
```

I expect that the script only tried to delete files in the folder where the script file is located.

How can I avoid this side effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not require `where` at all to do this, in fact I do not even recommend using where for this.

Just use `for /R` which will recurse through subdirectories, from the specified directory (where script was launched from).

```
@echo off
set "exten=*.dfs*"
for /R %%F in (%exten%) do (
   echo del "%%F"
)
```

If however you only want to delete files from the root directory where the script was launched, and not sub directories:

```
@echo off
set "exten=*.dfs*"
for %%F in (%exten%) do (
   echo del "%%F"
)
```

Remove `echo`, which were added as a failsafe, once you are happy with the output to screen. Addign `echo` to your original script would also have assisted you in not deleting files you never intended to delete, so do consider doing this next time.

for more information `for` command, open `cmd.exe` and run:

- `for /?`

Answer (score 0):

In your case `for` loop will enumerate all files from `where` output, regardless the current folder. Just run

```
where /f *.dfs*
```

in a command line and you'll see the issue: `where` is showing **all** files on the drive.
Use `/r` switch if you want to reduce the scope:

```
 /R       Recursively searches and displays the files that match the
          given pattern starting from the specified directory.
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`where` command](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html) also regards the system environment variables `PATH` and `PATHEXT` when searching files. To limit the search to the current directory, thus ignoring `PATH`, you need to prefix `.:`, like this:

```cmd
for /F "delims= eol=|" %%F in ('where ".:%exten%"') do (
    ECHO del "%%F"
)
```

However, this still regards `PATHEXT`, so this would also match something like `somefile.dfs.exe` – not sure if you want that…

---

Anyway, a better approach is to use a [`for` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) directly:

```cmd
for %%F in ("%exten%") do (
    ECHO del "%%~F"
)
```

Or you use the [`dir` command](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) instead:

```cmd
for /F "delims= eol=|" %%F in ('dir /B /A:-D "%exten%"') do (
    ECHO del "%%F"
)
```

---

But note that `where` treats wildcards not exactly the same way as `for` and `dir` (which are `cmd`-internal commands), because the latter also regard short [8.3 file names](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-filenames.html).

There are the following ways to avoid that:

1. using [`findstr`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) to filter the output or `dir /B`:

   ```cmd
   set "FILTER=\.dfs"
   for /F "delims= eol=|" %%F in ('dir /B /A:-D "%exten%" ^| findstr /I /E /C:"%FILTER%"') do (
       ECHO del "%%F"
   )
   ```

   Depending on the search criteria, you may need to add the `/R` option to `findstr`.
2. using `where` and temporarily deleting `PATHEXT`:

   ```cmd
   set "PE=%PATHEXT%" & set "PATHEXT="
   for /F "delims= eol=|" %%F in ('where ".:%exten%"') do (
       ECHO del "%%F"
   )
   set "PATHEXT=%PE%"
   ```

   Note that changing `PATHEXT` only affects this `cmd` instance and potential child instances.

After having tested the output, remove the upper-case `ECHO` to actually delete files.

Comment: Are you sure that `PATHEXT` is relevant to `where`? As far as I can see it's not.

Comment: Yes, @montonero; create a file `test.txt.exe` in the current directory and execute `where "test.txt"` or `where ".:test.txt"` therein...

Comment: You're right, thanks. I thought initially that it will only use `PATHEXT` if the file extension is not specified.

Answer (score 0):

Given your provided code and task, **to delete some files in a local folder, where the script is located**, I can see no reason whatsoever for implementing this through a `For` loop.

If all you're needing is to **delete all files whose extension begins with `.dfs` from the directory holding the running [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file)**, you only need a single line command:

```bat
@Del /Q "%~dp0*.dfs"
```

*Open up a Command Prompt window and enter **`del /?`** to read its usage information.*

Using the returned information, if you wanted to **delete files with any extension beginning with `.dfs` from  the directory holding the running script and all of its subdirectories**, then you'd use:

```bat
@Del /Q /S "%~dp0*.dfs"
```